# How do get $\rho_{BA}$ if I have $\rho_{AB}$

Tags: quantum-state, density-matrix

If Alice and Bob share the state:
$$\left| {{\psi _{AB}}} \right\rangle  = \sin \theta \left| {10} \right\rangle  + \cos \theta \left| {01} \right\rangle $$
then $\rho_{AB}$ can be obtained as:
$${\rho _{AB}} = \left| {{\psi _{AB}}} \right\rangle \left\langle {{\psi _{AB}}} \right|.$$
Is there a way to get $\rho_{BA}$ instead?

Comment: Crossposted from [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203918/how-do-get-rho-ba-if-i-have-rho-ab). I'm not sure why though, I already answered it on MSE.

Comment: what do you mean with "get". A quantum circuit sending one to the other? Also, what's your definition of $\rho_{BA}$ here? Is it the same state after swapping the spaces or something else?

Comment: @glS By $\rho_{BA}$ I mean the density matrix after permutation of the subsystems. I want to get the formula that enables me to calculate $\rho_{BA}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are *labels* for the Hilbert spaces in which each subsystem exists. There is no different physical content between $\mathcal{H}_A\otimes \mathcal{H}_B$ and $\mathcal{H}_B\otimes \mathcal{H}_A$, they are just different ways of bookkeeping.

As such, we can immediately trade all of the information about subspaces $A$ and $B$ and write
$$|\psi_{BA}\rangle=\sin\theta |0\rangle_B\otimes|1\rangle_A+\cos\theta |1\rangle_B\otimes|0\rangle_A$$ and $$\rho_{BA}=|\psi_{BA}\rangle\langle \psi_{BA}|.$$

Comment: What about the coefficients $\sin \theta $ and $\cos \theta $? Won't they have any change?

Comment: Nope, no change! We are simply changing the labels - I'll make it more explicit